# JQ extract error for key containing pipe character

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am trying to extract the value for something|something key in my below JSON but getting a compile error

```
  {
    "properties": {
      "Anything": "ABCD",
      "something|something": "unknown"
    }
  }
```

The filter `.properties | .something|something` is giving me below error when I try it in [Jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/).

> jq: error: something/0 is not defined at , line 1:
> .properties | .something|something
> jq: 1 compile error
> exit status 3

Comment: The.`parent.foo` form is just a shortcut. Use `parent["foo"]` for the general case.

Comment: We have a duplicate for this, I'll try to find it in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround `something|something` with quotes in order to escape the pipe character:

```
.properties."something|something"
```

**[jqplay snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/moPXSMjSQz)**

Comment: *grumble* answering obvious duplicates *grumble* (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, third bullet point)

Comment: (...granted, the other duplicates aren't asked about the pipe character specifically, but the answers are all the same, and we don't need a separate question for every single possible illegal character).